# Detect the Text of multi textBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have  program with multi methods . 
We create all the controls with methods . 
One of methods is for creating textBox . It is like :

```
 private TextBox textBox1;

   public void CreateTextBox()
    {

        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, Position);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        Position += 30;
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);

    }
```

There are several textBoxes in a form (the count of textbox might change between 10 to 20 ) .
So , If I want to create several textBoxes , Call methods like :

```
        CreateTextBox();
        CreateTextBox();
        CreateTextBox();
```

If I want to have the Text of this textboxes , A code like this return me the last textBox Text :

```
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
```

My problem is ,,,, How can I detect the text of first called of CreateTextBox() and second called of CreateTextBox() ?
Thank u for read

Comment: Make your code return a TextBox and store them in a List.

Comment: Or just give them different names.

Comment: Or use `Tag` and loop through them... Whatever makes most sense...

Comment: or give them different names and store the names in a `List<String>` and reference them via `Controls()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array containing all `TextBoxes`:

```
var form = new Form();

var boxes = new TextBox[10];
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
{
    var box = new TextBox();
    box.Location = new Point(10, 30 + 25 * i);
    box.Size = new Size(100, 20);
    form.Controls.Add(box);

    boxes[i] = box;
}

var button = new Button();
button.Text = "Button";
button.Click += (o, e) =>
{
    var message = String.Join(", ", boxes.Select(tb => tb.Text));
    MessageBox.Show(message);
};
form.Controls.Add(button);

Application.Run(form);
```